# From an org item, launch a shell command with the item text as parameter

Tags: org-mode, shell, shell-command

From an org list item, I want **a function that I can bind** to a *shortkey* or an *`org-speed` shortcut*, to be able to launch a shell command with the **org list item text as parameter**. Then I want to add tag to the item

```
* item one
* item I two  ← caret is here 
* item three
```

I want to launch a command shell like

```
./my_command "item two" ← this is returning a short uuid
```

then adding a tag

```
* item one
* item two           :b7acda1e:  ← the tag added from previous command line
* item three
```

I'm not a elisp developer, but they told me `org-element could help here

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  three things to do, so we write a function for each:

- get the headline text
- run the command with the headline text as argument
- add the result as a tag to the headline

```el
(defun ndk/headline-text ()
  (let* ((el (org-element-at-point))
         (typ (org-element-type el)))
    (when (eq typ 'headline)
      (plist-get (cadr el) :raw-value))))

(defun ndk/run-my-command (arg)
  (unless (null arg)
    (shell-command (concat "/tmp/command" " " arg))
    (with-current-buffer shell-command-buffer-name
      (buffer-substring-no-properties  (point-min) (point-max)))))

(defun ndk/insert-tag (tag)
  (unless (null tag)
    (let ((tags (org-get-tags)))
      (unless (member tag tags)
         (org-set-tags (cons tag tags))))))

(defun ndk/do-it ()
  (interactive)
  (ndk/insert-tag (ndk/run-my-command (ndk/headline-text))))
```

The `ndk/do-it` command then just composes the three functions. You can bind it to a key if you want:

```el
(define-key org-mode-map "C-c t" #'ndk/do-it)
```

You will need to customize the path to your command (`/tmp/command` above).

The functions take some pains to act reasonably even under unreasonable usage: they all return `nil` on error and the functions `ndk/run-my-command` and `ndk/insert-tag` do nothing if their argument is `nil`. Moreover, `ndk/insert-tag` checks whether the tag exists already before adding it.

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'll test tomorrow and validate it